# Qb64 How to Move sprite made by data tables

Tags: qb64

I'm trying to make a top down test game, but i want to use a sprite made by a data table, how would i go around to doing that, this is what i have currently.

```
SCREEN 12
DIM keypress AS STRING
DIM x AS INTEGER
DIM y AS INTEGER
DIM c AS INTEGER
CONST size = 5
x = 320
y = 200
c = 5
CLS

DO
    keypress = UCASE$(INKEY$)
    IF keypress = "A" AND x > size THEN
        x = x - 1
        CLS
    ELSEIF keypress = "D" AND x < 480 - size THEN
        x = x + 1
        CLS
    ELSEIF keypress = "W" AND y > size THEN
        y = y - 1
        CLS
    ELSEIF keypress = "S" AND y < 640 - size THEN
        y = y + 1
        CLS
        CIRCLE (x, y), size, c
    END IF
    COLOR
LOOP UNTIL keypress = "Q"

sprite_1:
 DATA line (320,200)-(350,200)
 DATA line (350,200)-(350,210)
 DATA line (360,210)-(350,210)
 DATA line (350,210)-(250,200)
```

would i have to make each point on the Data table a variable ad make them defined?